# Looping through tables in a table in Lua

Tags: c++, loops, lua, lua-table

I've hit a complete dead end with this. This is probably going to be something incredibly basic and it will most likely result in me smashing my head into a wall for having a major brain fart. My question is basically, how do you loop though tables in lua if the entries are tables themselves?

C++:

```
lua_newtable(luaState);
    for(auto rec : recpay) {
        lua_newtable(luaState);

        lua_pushnumber(luaState, rec.amount);
        lua_setfield(luaState, -2, "Amount");

        lua_pushnumber(luaState, rec.units);
        lua_setfield(luaState, -2, "Units");

        lua_setfield(luaState, -2, rec.type);
    }
lua_setglobal(luaState, "RecuringPayments");
```

Lua:

```
for _,RecWT in ipairs(RecuringPayments) do
    -- RecWT.Amount = nil?
end
```

Comment: I guess you might just want recursive traversal.

Answer (score 1):

In your C++ code it looks like you're setting the subtable by string as a key rather than by index. To traverse that entry you have to use `pairs` instead:

```
for recType, RecWT in pairs(RecuringPayments) do
  assert(RecWT.Amount ~= nil)
end
```

Note that `ipairs` only traverses the index part of the table, the associative part is ignored.

Alternatively, if you want to use index access then you have to set the key-value with `lua_settable` instead:

```
lua_newtable(luaState);
int i = 0;
for(auto rec : recpay)
{
    lua_newtable(luaState);

    lua_pushnumber(luaState, rec.amount);
    lua_setfield(luaState, -2, "Amount");

    lua_pushnumber(luaState, rec.units);
    lua_setfield(luaState, -2, "Units");

    lua_pushnumber(luaState, ++i);
    lua_insert(luaState, -2);
    lua_settable(luaState, -3);
}
lua_setglobal(luaState, "RecuringPayments");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function that traverses tables:

```
function traversetable(tab, array)
    local iteratefunc = array and ipairs or pairs
    for k, v in iteratefunc(tab) do
        if type(v) == "table" then
            traversetable(v, array)    --Assumes that type is the same as the parent's table
        else
            --Do other stuff
        end
    end
end
```

This is just a basic example, but gives you a rough idea. `array` is a boolean value indicating, whether it's a one-based array or not.